# Android logcat - not ouputing double new line - String with double new line - String equals

Tags: java, android, string, newline, android-logcat

I'm testing a method in my app. I'm generating a vcard from a stored contact and comparing it to an hardcoded vcard. They should be the exact same `vcard`, and they are. The problem is the test is failing and don't understand how.

From the `logcat` output it looks obvious that it is not printing a double new line (`\n\n`)

Here is my code:

```
public void testGetContactAsVcard() {

    String vcardActual = utils.getContactAsVcard(contact.getAllContactIds().get(0));

    // This is the vcard for the first contact (position zero)
    String vcardExpected = "BEGIN:VCARD" +
            "\nVERSION:2.1" +
            "\nN:Klisnmann;Jurgen;;;" +
            "\nFN:Jurgen Klinsmann" +
            "\nX-ANDROID-CUSTOM:vnd.android.cursor.item/nickname;mynickname;;;;;;;;;;;;;;" +
            "\nTEL;CELL:922-222-222" +
            "\nTEL;WORK:911-222-333" +
            "\nEMAIL;WORK:work@mail.com" +
            "\nEMAIL;HOME:home@mail.com" +
            "\nADR;WORK:poBox;;StreetSomething;Berlin Alexanderplatz;Berlin;28000;Germany" +
            "\nADR;HOME:poBox;;MyStreet20;Berlin Potsdam;Berlin;2800;Germany" +
            "\nORG:MAT\\;MobileDept." +
            "\nTITLE:Eng." +
            "\nURL:www.company.com" +
            "\nURL:myblog.com" +
            "\nURL:custom.com" +
            "\nPHOTO;ENCODING=BASE64;JPEG:/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAMCAgMCAgMDAwM" +
            "\n EAwMEBQgFBQQEBQoHBwYIDAoMDAsKCwsNDhIQDQ4RDgsLEBYQERMUFRUVDA8XGBYUGBIUFRT/" +
            "\n 2wBDAQMEBAUEBQkFBQkUDQsNFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUF" +
            "\n BQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBT/wAARCAAkAGADASIAAhEBAxEB/8QAHwAAAQUBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAA" +
            "\n ECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtRAAAgEDAwIEAwUFBAQAAAF9AQIDAAQRBRIhMUEGE1FhByJxFDKBkaE" +
            "\n II0KxwRVS0fAkM2JyggkKFhcYGRolJicoKSo0NTY3ODk6Q0RFRkdISUpTVFVWV1hZWmNkZWZn" +
            "\n aGlqc3R1dnd4eXqDhIWGh4iJipKTlJWWl5iZmqKjpKWmp6ipqrKztLW2t7i5usLDxMXGx8jJy" +
            "\n tLT1NXW19jZ2uHi4+Tl5ufo6erx8vP09fb3+Pn6/8QAHwEAAwEBAQEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAECAw" +
            "\n QFBgcICQoL/8QAtREAAgECBAQDBAcFBAQAAQJ3AAECAxEEBSExBhJBUQdhcRMiMoEIFEKRobH" +
            "\n BCSMzUvAVYnLRChYkNOEl8RcYGRomJygpKjU2Nzg5OkNERUZHSElKU1RVVldYWVpjZGVmZ2hp" +
            "\n anN0dXZ3eHl6goOEhYaHiImKkpOUlZaXmJmaoqOkpaanqKmqsrO0tba3uLm6wsPExcbHyMnK0" +
            "\n tPU1dbX2Nna4uPk5ebn6Onq8vP09fb3+Pn6/9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwD778e+J/Gem65qtvo1hq" +
            "\n 1xEvlm0ktrSN4MeWC4JMZZiW44OBn2xXis3xn/AGjl0Cyv4vhRrD3rrbG60trmzWeLc0iziNv" +
            "\n LMchj2Iy5dA6yryjBkH0z4v8ACOjeMrq1tNd8MLrlnAsjq9wI3gbzYZraWOSNmHmKYZ5QVZWU" +
            "\n iTpkDGdtg0fw/peoSeG/E0kklrb6e+lvfG8njFxJBCwuALh45HjAVnnLOVRZSJCGbd1RxCXLC" +
            "\n ME3tt+tnvonta76rXilQbbk5v8AHv5M8/8A+Er+J3/PDUv/AAVL/wDG6uaB4n+JE/iTSoby3v" +
            "\n hpsk6LcySaeEwu9QR/qum3dlsjGB1zkeneAPDuneFvCGm6dpejzaBaIjS/2fdSiWeOSRjJKZp" +
            "\n A8nmStI7s8hdy7szFmJJPQVp9ai42dOKf9eRH1SUZXVWTX9eYUUUVwnoBWb4m1RtD8OatqSmM" +
            "\n NZ2ktwDN9wFEZvm5HHHPIrSrlPiz/wAks8Zf9ga8/wDRD0AeIeMPiX8Z9KN2+geD9b1wR2KGC" +
            "\n A29tCZrsJcM4Lso2RsUt0U7WIabJyoYrytz8a/2j0YSQfCTWpbc2c1xse6sknEwmKQwFdhTcy" +
            "\n bJWbftRd4BkdVV/fNV0rf4m0vUZfBfiO6ure/QRT6draJa26tPdIbh4mu4wVCSGWVRGzMssSh" +
            "\n ZWiCx7EngfSotd0HUBYaxdXtiJ7KG7bV52FvC6l3Moef96jtHGMEO27yiQAm5OxYi7XuJaX6e" +
            "\n fdenn5dHwPDSjf32/m/Ls/X+tvBdU+Lfxx0uXUlT4eeJNWS3uYI7Z9NhscXULx7pJR5xiKGNw" +
            "\n yFW+9mMqSGfy/S/AfiLx/feMbS31qC7TSGVi8ktkIwW2OcMfLG0ZCYO7kkjA79d4k+DvgrxnN" +
            "\n HL4l8NWHiYx2n2JE12P7fGkOQWASbcoLlU3tjc/lpuLbFx2NH1hOLi4LX0/wAkOOGlGSftHp6" +
            "\n 6/j1MPWtQiXUbPT5E1SJrkhI7qygd4txDEq7qCIwAmdz7V5UBstg+CXnwign1i31GT4mfHExa" +
            "\n 74fewt5oZ5UgsPNltx5zW62oaG7YXbAPNGfKVJmxEYEZPTfHniPUZtZfTbDVLzQ/sodGns7mz" +
            "\n QzNJAwQkXEEuNjMHUjA3Iu/cpKmjffE+7ayRlW4t/OkSRZILy3aRVQpuQqYW2q+0g7hnEjbSM" +
            "\n KV5oN025Q62v8AK9vzv8nfodjSerV7X8t9/wAhPBep3llqN/pUuifEJl0i/Ed9rutS28kWoub" +
            "\n YytcRokpLRHy4l8u1iRBJchEjGycQ9dD421CXxVa6R/whfiCOxnLg645sxZxYTcN6/aPOG4go" +
            "\n MRH5hzgFSfPYviLqMev22oNqesSWkXm79KaWz+zTb3kZdzC0Eo2B1Vdsi5ESbtxLl+l0z4yLq" +
            "\n Gt2GmnSHje6cIJBKzKo3KpJOzGfmGASCcHHQ4540VSd4NO/l/w34L7zWU3Pf+vvuekUUUVqQF" +
            "\n cj8XoI7j4VeMVljWVRpF24V1BAZYXKn6ggEehArrqz/EOnyatoGp2MLIs1zaywoXJChmQgZxn" +
            "\n jmgDy34u/C3TfHzaBd3vjD4k+HbLR/tFitr4R1K9tBevcHyEkuPIQzSeSyLIkhIRc73LozZ6X" +
            "\n wj4bddRl1h9c8XXVrLI11ZaLq7rHFa5EisRhFkYSeYXEVzI/lnYFSHYFXh4vBPipXiaTwvBNs" +
            "\n GCrXaKH4wM7ZB7cjGcc55zWPw98Wkk/2Fj2F5F/8VWvsanLZSX3r/P+vvvze0p31T+5/wCR6L" +
            "\n 4Z+KFxrtnc3l74H8V+HbS3muoHk1OzhZy0EkceUhgmlldZGeTy2VCrLbu+QjwtLpeBvGl3400" +
            "\n rT9Qm8J674ZhvbCK+WLXUt4poi7OPIkijmd0lVVVmUjAEijO8OqeUf8K88W/9AP8A8nIf/iq2" +
            "\n oqCwooooAKKKKACiiigD/2Q==" +
            "\n\nNOTE:Somenotes..." +
            "\nX-ANDROID-CUSTOM:vnd.android.cursor.item/contact_event;1985-07-20;1;;;;;;;;;;;;;" +
            "\nEND:VCARD";

    Log.d(TAG, "vcard actual: " + vcardActual);
    Log.d(TAG, "vcard expected: " + vcardExpected);
    assertEquals(vcardExpected, vcardActual);
}
```

And here is the `logcat` output:

```
vcard actual: 

BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
N:Klisnmann;Jurgen;;;
FN:Jurgen Klinsmann
X-ANDROID-CUSTOM:vnd.android.cursor.item/nickname;mynickname;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
TEL;CELL:922-222-222
TEL;WORK:911-222-333
EMAIL;WORK:work@mail.com
EMAIL;HOME:home@mail.com
ADR;WORK:poBox;;StreetSomething;Berlin Alexanderplatz;Berlin;28000;Germany
ADR;HOME:poBox;;MyStreet20;Berlin Potsdam;Berlin;2800;Germany
ORG:MAT\;MobileDept.
TITLE:Eng.
URL:www.company.com
URL:myblog.com
URL:custom.com
PHOTO;ENCODING=BASE64;JPEG:/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAMCAgMCAgMDAwM
 EAwMEBQgFBQQEBQoHBwYIDAoMDAsKCwsNDhIQDQ4RDgsLEBYQERMUFRUVDA8XGBYUGBIUFRT/
 2wBDAQMEBAUEBQkFBQkUDQsNFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUF
 BQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBT/wAARCAAkAGADASIAAhEBAxEB/8QAHwAAAQUBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAA
 ECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtRAAAgEDAwIEAwUFBAQAAAF9AQIDAAQRBRIhMUEGE1FhByJxFDKBkaE
 II0KxwRVS0fAkM2JyggkKFhcYGRolJicoKSo0NTY3ODk6Q0RFRkdISUpTVFVWV1hZWmNkZWZn
 aGlqc3R1dnd4eXqDhIWGh4iJipKTlJWWl5iZmqKjpKWmp6ipqrKztLW2t7i5usLDxMXGx8jJy
 tLT1NXW19jZ2uHi4+Tl5ufo6erx8vP09fb3+Pn6/8QAHwEAAwEBAQEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAECAw
 QFBgcICQoL/8QAtREAAgECBAQDBAcFBAQAAQJ3AAECAxEEBSExBhJBUQdhcRMiMoEIFEKRobH
 BCSMzUvAVYnLRChYkNOEl8RcYGRomJygpKjU2Nzg5OkNERUZHSElKU1RVVldYWVpjZGVmZ2hp
 anN0dXZ3eHl6goOEhYaHiImKkpOUlZaXmJmaoqOkpaanqKmqsrO0tba3uLm6wsPExcbHyMnK0
 tPU1dbX2Nna4uPk5ebn6Onq8vP09fb3+Pn6/9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwD778e+J/Gem65qtvo1hq
 1xEvlm0ktrSN4MeWC4JMZZiW44OBn2xXis3xn/AGjl0Cyv4vhRrD3rrbG60trmzWeLc0iziNv
 LMchj2Iy5dA6yryjBkH0z4v8ACOjeMrq1tNd8MLrlnAsjq9wI3gbzYZraWOSNmHmKYZ5QVZWU
 iTpkDGdtg0fw/peoSeG/E0kklrb6e+lvfG8njFxJBCwuALh45HjAVnnLOVRZSJCGbd1RxCXLC
 ME3tt+tnvonta76rXilQbbk5v8AHv5M8/8A+Er+J3/PDUv/AAVL/wDG6uaB4n+JE/iTSoby3v
 hpsk6LcySaeEwu9QR/qum3dlsjGB1zkeneAPDuneFvCGm6dpejzaBaIjS/2fdSiWeOSRjJKZp
 A8nmStI7s8hdy7szFmJJPQVp9ai42dOKf9eRH1SUZXVWTX9eYUUUVwnoBWb4m1RtD8OatqSmM
 NZ2ktwDN9wFEZvm5HHHPIrSrlPiz/wAks8Zf9ga8/wDRD0AeIeMPiX8Z9KN2+geD9b1wR2KGC
 A29tCZrsJcM4Lso2RsUt0U7WIabJyoYrytz8a/2j0YSQfCTWpbc2c1xse6sknEwmKQwFdhTcy
 bJWbftRd4BkdVV/fNV0rf4m0vUZfBfiO6ure/QRT6draJa26tPdIbh4mu4wVCSGWVRGzMssSh
 ZWiCx7EngfSotd0HUBYaxdXtiJ7KG7bV52FvC6l3Moef96jtHGMEO27yiQAm5OxYi7XuJaX6e
 fdenn5dHwPDSjf32/m/Ls/X+tvBdU+Lfxx0uXUlT4eeJNWS3uYI7Z9NhscXULx7pJR5xiKGNw
 yFW+9mMqSGfy/S/AfiLx/feMbS31qC7TSGVi8ktkIwW2OcMfLG0ZCYO7kkjA79d4k+DvgrxnN
 HL4l8NWHiYx2n2JE12P7fGkOQWASbcoLlU3tjc/lpuLbFx2NH1hOLi4LX0/wAkOOGlGSftHp6
 6/j1MPWtQiXUbPT5E1SJrkhI7qygd4txDEq7qCIwAmdz7V5UBstg+CXnwign1i31GT4mfHExa
 74fewt5oZ5UgsPNltx5zW62oaG7YXbAPNGfKVJmxEYEZPTfHniPUZtZfTbDVLzQ/sodGns7mz
 QzNJAwQkXEEuNjMHUjA3Iu/cpKmjffE+7ayRlW4t/OkSRZILy3aRVQpuQqYW2q+0g7hnEjbSM
 KV5oN025Q62v8AK9vzv8nfodjSerV7X8t9/wAhPBep3llqN/pUuifEJl0i/Ed9rutS28kWoub
 YytcRokpLRHy4l8u1iRBJchEjGycQ9dD421CXxVa6R/whfiCOxnLg645sxZxYTcN6/aPOG4go
 MRH5hzgFSfPYviLqMev22oNqesSWkXm79KaWz+zTb3kZdzC0Eo2B1Vdsi5ESbtxLl+l0z4yLq
 Gt2GmnSHje6cIJBKzKo3KpJOzGfmGASCcHHQ4540VSd4NO/l/w34L7zWU3Pf+vvuekUUUVqQF
 cj8XoI7j4VeMVljWVRpF24V1BAZYXKn6ggEehArrqz/EOnyatoGp2MLIs1zaywoXJChmQgZxn
 jmgDy34u/C3TfHzaBd3vjD4k+HbLR/tFitr4R1K9tBevcHyEkuPIQzSeSyLIkhIRc73LozZ6X
 wj4bddRl1h9c8XXVrLI11ZaLq7rHFa5EisRhFkYSeYXEVzI/lnYFSHYFXh4vBPipXiaTwvBNs
 GCrXaKH4wM7ZB7cjGcc55zWPw98Wkk/2Fj2F5F/8VWvsanLZSX3r/P+vvvze0p31T+5/wCR6L
 4Z+KFxrtnc3l74H8V+HbS3muoHk1OzhZy0EkceUhgmlldZGeTy2VCrLbu+QjwtLpeBvGl3400
 rT9Qm8J674ZhvbCK+WLXUt4poi7OPIkijmd0lVVVmUjAEijO8OqeUf8K88W/9AP8A8nIf/iq2
 oqCwooooAKKKKACiiigD/2Q==

NOTE:Somenotes...
X-ANDROID-CUSTOM:vnd.android.cursor.item/contact_event;1985-07-20;1;;;;;;;;;;;;;
END:VCARD



vcard expected: 

BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
N:Klisnmann;Jurgen;;;
FN:Jurgen Klinsmann
X-ANDROID-CUSTOM:vnd.android.cursor.item/nickname;mynickname;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
TEL;CELL:922-222-222
TEL;WORK:911-222-333
EMAIL;WORK:work@mail.com
EMAIL;HOME:home@mail.com
ADR;WORK:poBox;;StreetSomething;Berlin Alexanderplatz;Berlin;28000;Germany
ADR;HOME:poBox;;MyStreet20;Berlin Potsdam;Berlin;2800;Germany
ORG:MAT\;MobileDept.
TITLE:Eng.
URL:www.company.com
URL:myblog.com
URL:custom.com
PHOTO;ENCODING=BASE64;JPEG:/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAMCAgMCAgMDAwM
 EAwMEBQgFBQQEBQoHBwYIDAoMDAsKCwsNDhIQDQ4RDgsLEBYQERMUFRUVDA8XGBYUGBIUFRT/
 2wBDAQMEBAUEBQkFBQkUDQsNFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUF
 BQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBT/wAARCAAkAGADASIAAhEBAxEB/8QAHwAAAQUBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAA
 ECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtRAAAgEDAwIEAwUFBAQAAAF9AQIDAAQRBRIhMUEGE1FhByJxFDKBkaE
 II0KxwRVS0fAkM2JyggkKFhcYGRolJicoKSo0NTY3ODk6Q0RFRkdISUpTVFVWV1hZWmNkZWZn
 aGlqc3R1dnd4eXqDhIWGh4iJipKTlJWWl5iZmqKjpKWmp6ipqrKztLW2t7i5usLDxMXGx8jJy
 tLT1NXW19jZ2uHi4+Tl5ufo6erx8vP09fb3+Pn6/8QAHwEAAwEBAQEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAECAw
 QFBgcICQoL/8QAtREAAgECBAQDBAcFBAQAAQJ3AAECAxEEBSExBhJBUQdhcRMiMoEIFEKRobH
 BCSMzUvAVYnLRChYkNOEl8RcYGRomJygpKjU2Nzg5OkNERUZHSElKU1RVVldYWVpjZGVmZ2hp
 anN0dXZ3eHl6goOEhYaHiImKkpOUlZaXmJmaoqOkpaanqKmqsrO0tba3uLm6wsPExcbHyMnK0
 tPU1dbX2Nna4uPk5ebn6Onq8vP09fb3+Pn6/9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwD778e+J/Gem65qtvo1hq
 1xEvlm0ktrSN4MeWC4JMZZiW44OBn2xXis3xn/AGjl0Cyv4vhRrD3rrbG60trmzWeLc0iziNv
 LMchj2Iy5dA6yryjBkH0z4v8ACOjeMrq1tNd8MLrlnAsjq9wI3gbzYZraWOSNmHmKYZ5QVZWU
 iTpkDGdtg0fw/peoSeG/E0kklrb6e+lvfG8njFxJBCwuALh45HjAVnnLOVRZSJCGbd1RxCXLC
 ME3tt+tnvonta76rXilQbbk5v8AHv5M8/8A+Er+J3/PDUv/AAVL/wDG6uaB4n+JE/iTSoby3v
 hpsk6LcySaeEwu9QR/qum3dlsjGB1zkeneAPDuneFvCGm6dpejzaBaIjS/2fdSiWeOSRjJKZp
 A8nmStI7s8hdy7szFmJJPQVp9ai42dOKf9eRH1SUZXVWTX9eYUUUVwnoBWb4m1RtD8OatqSmM
 NZ2ktwDN9wFEZvm5HHHPIrSrlPiz/wAks8Zf9ga8/wDRD0AeIeMPiX8Z9KN2+geD9b1wR2KGC
 A29tCZrsJcM4Lso2RsUt0U7WIabJyoYrytz8a/2j0YSQfCTWpbc2c1xse6sknEwmKQwFdhTcy
 bJWbftRd4BkdVV/fNV0rf4m0vUZfBfiO6ure/QRT6draJa26tPdIbh4mu4wVCSGWVRGzMssSh
 ZWiCx7EngfSotd0HUBYaxdXtiJ7KG7bV52FvC6l3Moef96jtHGMEO27yiQAm5OxYi7XuJaX6e
 fdenn5dHwPDSjf32/m/Ls/X+tvBdU+Lfxx0uXUlT4eeJNWS3uYI7Z9NhscXULx7pJR5xiKGNw
 yFW+9mMqSGfy/S/AfiLx/feMbS31qC7TSGVi8ktkIwW2OcMfLG0ZCYO7kkjA79d4k+DvgrxnN
 HL4l8NWHiYx2n2JE12P7fGkOQWASbcoLlU3tjc/lpuLbFx2NH1hOLi4LX0/wAkOOGlGSftHp6
 6/j1MPWtQiXUbPT5E1SJrkhI7qygd4txDEq7qCIwAmdz7V5UBstg+CXnwign1i31GT4mfHExa
 74fewt5oZ5UgsPNltx5zW62oaG7YXbAPNGfKVJmxEYEZPTfHniPUZtZfTbDVLzQ/sodGns7mz
 QzNJAwQkXEEuNjMHUjA3Iu/cpKmjffE+7ayRlW4t/OkSRZILy3aRVQpuQqYW2q+0g7hnEjbSM
 KV5oN025Q62v8AK9vzv8nfodjSerV7X8t9/wAhPBep3llqN/pUuifEJl0i/Ed9rutS28kWoub
 YytcRokpLRHy4l8u1iRBJchEjGycQ9dD421CXxVa6R/whfiCOxnLg645sxZxYTcN6/aPOG4go
 MRH5hzgFSfPYviLqMev22oNqesSWkXm79KaWz+zTb3kZdzC0Eo2B1Vdsi5ESbtxLl+l0z4yLq
 Gt2GmnSHje6cIJBKzKo3KpJOzGfmGASCcHHQ4540VSd4NO/l/w34L7zWU3Pf+vvuekUUUVqQF
 cj8XoI7j4VeMVljWVRpF24V1BAZYXKn6ggEehArrqz/EOnyatoGp2MLIs1zaywoXJChmQgZxn
 jmgDy34u/C3TfHzaBd3vjD4k+HbLR/tFitr4R1K9tBevcHyEkuPIQzSeSyLIkhIRc73LozZ6X
 wj4bddRl1h9c8XXVrLI11ZaLq7rHFa5EisRhFkYSeYXEVzI/lnYFSHYFXh4vBPipXiaTwvBNs
 GCrXaKH4wM7ZB7cjGcc55zWPw98Wkk/2Fj2F5F/8VWvsanLZSX3r/P+vvvze0p31T+5/wCR6L
 4Z+KFxrtnc3l74H8V+HbS3muoHk1OzhZy0EkceUhgmlldZGeTy2VCrLbu+QjwtLpeBvGl3400
 rT9Qm8J674ZhvbCK+WLXUt4poi7OPIkijmd0lVVVmUjAEijO8OqeUf8K88W/9AP8A8nIf/iq2
 oqCwooooAKKKKACiiigD/2Q==
NOTE:Somenotes...
X-ANDROID-CUSTOM:vnd.android.cursor.item/contact_event;1985-07-20;1;;;;;;;;;;;;;
END:VCARD
```

As you can see, in the `vcardActual` between the `PHOTO` and the `NOTE` there is a new empty line but that does not happen in the `vcardExpected` even tho I've placed a `\n\n` before the `NOTE`.

I would expect an empty new line between `PHOTO` and `NOTE` but for some reason it does not happen. Why and how is this happening?

Comment: Are you sure you showed the results correctly?  Your _actual_ does contain an empty line.

Comment: @AleksG do you mean the empty line between `PHOTO` and `NOTE`? if so, yes it is the only difference but I did put a `\n\n` there in my `vcardExpected` variable (please check the code) but it is not showing up, that is my question. Why it does not show or print a new empty line between `PHOTO` and `NOTE`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution.

First -> **Never rely solely on logcat!** The new line was ALWAYS there but logcat wasn't outputting it for some reason that I don't know yet.

Second -> JUnit was adding a `[`, `]`, `<`, `>` and a `new line`.

Solution: Remove all whitespaces and new lines from both strings and compare them.

```
final String vcardNoWhiteSpacesNoNewLinesExpected = vcardExpected.replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "").replace(" ", "");
final String vcardNoWhiteSpacesNoNewLinesActual = vcardActual.replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "").replace(" ", "");
```

They both match now, problem solved.